# Unable to send Push notification using WNS on Windows phone 8.1 Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, azure, windows-phone-8.1, azure-notificationhub

We have just upgraded our existing Windows phone 8 Silverlight app to Windows phone 8.1 Silverlight project with the help from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642085(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_UsingWNS) Basically we want to use WNS to send push notification and not MPNS. We changed the notificaiton type to WNS in menifest file. We added the tile in package.menifest file.

When we are registering the app we get the app id but notification is not being received on the app. We are using Azure notification hub to send the notification using WNS. When we look at the azure notification explorer it shows the registration but the platform is still MPNS. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to open the link, but it seems like on registration, the service is noting the request with platform MPNS. Are you using the client SDKs or using REST directly? If REST, I would make sure the platform is set correctly. You will also need to update the WNS certificate with Notification Hubs in the Azure Portal.

Comment: I've updated the link you should be able to open this. Now when you use WNS you don't really need to update certificate it works on OAuth and we just have to configure package id and client secret from developer account. We are using Notification Hub of azure to send push notification.